# "NVRM: Xid" error in terminal

Tags: nvidia, 18.04, additional-drivers

I am running Ubuntu 18.04.

When I boot up my machine I keep seeing the same error over and over in my terminal, every few seconds

```
NVRM: Xid (PCI:0000:01:00): 16, Head 00000002 Count 00002b25
```

Someone told me that it might be graphics related, even though i am not sure of that. I am using the propetary drivers for NVIDIA, version 396.

Also my dmesg is [here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/zrwhzV7gWZ/)